# Wordpress on a local machine redirecting to online url

Tags: local-installation

i've downloaded a wordpress web to my local machine and tried setting it up.
the problem: when trying to login, wordpress will always redirect to the online url.
the only way i found was changing the siteurl manually in phpmyadmin to my local machine's ip address.
is there a better solution?
the problem about doing that is that permalinks won't work anymore locally.

thanks

Comment: Not sure why that means the permalinks don't work locally anymore?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Open up your `wp-config.php` file

Try adding the following to it:

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://localhost/your_wordpress_folder' );  
define( 'WP_HOME',    'http://localhost/your_wordpress_folder' );
```

Comment: the only thing to add here is to go to Settings > Permalinks and resave, so that you get a correct .htaccess file

Answer (score 4):

If I understand right you had restored backup of live site to local installation?

Basically you have two ways to handle it:

1. [Change site URL](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) (I recommend `RELOCATE` way, always works nicely for me).
2. Use [hosts file of your OS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_file) to point live domain at your local IP (`127.0.0.1`).